# Getting Text Between Two Strings In a File

Tags: python

i am trying to get the string of a "start" and "end" of a file. I am somewhat successful but the isssue i am having is that its duplicating it in my output file. I am most certain its because of that third for loop. I need that third for loop because i have two "ends" that i am iterating through. Is there a solution where I can iterate through the "end" keys without duplicating the writing to my output file?

file 1:

```
TEXT NOT NEEDED
12345-67897
[more text here]
AMOUNT POSTED: $43,000.00
Text not needed
```

file 2:

```
TEXT NOT NEEDED
12345-67897
[more  text here]
N= None Billable, B= Billable
TEXT NOT NEEDED
```

code:

```
start_key = '12345-67897'
end_key = ['AMOUNT POSTED: $43,000.00', 'N= None Billable, B= Billable']
input_fp = ['C:\User\inputfilepath.txt', 'C:\User\inputfilepath2.txt']
output_fp = ['C:\User\outputfilepath.txt', 'C:\User\outputfilepath2.txt']

    for fp, ofp in zip(input_fp,output_fp):
        with open(fp, 'r') as file, open(ofp, 'w') as ofp:
            parsing = False
            for line in file:
                for ek in end_key:
                    if start_key in line.strip():
                        parsing = True
                    if ek in line.strip():
                        parsing = False
                    if parsing:
                        ofp.write(line)
```

current output:

File 1:

```
12345-67897
12345-67897
[more text here]
[more text here]
AMOUNT POSTED: $43,000.00
AMOUNT POSTED: $43,000.00
```

File 2:

```
12345-67897
12345-67897
[more  text here]
[more  text here]
N= None Billable, B= Billable
N= None Billable, B= Billable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to check if start key is in the input line **before** looping over the end tags. Add one check for parsing flag is true **after** the loop. This will ensure line is output once. Also, don't need to strip the line input each time.

Try this:

```python
for fp, ofp in zip(input_fp, output_fp):
    with open(fp, 'r') as file, open(ofp, 'w') as ofp:
        parsing = False
        for line in file:
            if start_key in line:
                parsing = True
            for ek in end_key:
                if ek in line:
                    parsing = False
                    break
            if parsing:
                ofp.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, i found that 3rd loop makes call write function twice!

I recommends you to split condition for your conditional loop like below.

```
start_key = '12345-67897'
end_key = ['AMOUNT POSTED: $43,000.00', 'N= None Billable, B= Billable']
input_fp = ['./inputfilepath.txt', './inputfilepath2.txt']
output_fp = ['./outputfilepath.txt', './outputfilepath2.txt']

for fp, ofp in zip(input_fp,output_fp):
    with open(fp, 'r') as file, open(ofp, 'w') as ofp:
        parsing = False
        for line in file:

            line_striped = line.strip()

            # Starting condition
            if start_key in line_striped:
                parsing = True
            
            # Writing condition
            if parsing:
                ofp.write(line)

            # Stop condition
            if any([ek in line_striped for ek in end_key]):
                break
```

output outputfilepath.txt

```
12345-67897
[more text here]
AMOUNT POSTED: $43,000.00
```

output outputfilepath2.txt

```
12345-67897
[more  text here]
N= None Billable, B= Billable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to find and extract the text, then just get the result from regex and save in the other file:

```
import re

start_key = '12345-67897\n'
end_key = 'AMOUNT POSTED: \$43,000\.00'
input_fp = 'test.txt'
output_fp = 'test2.txt'

with open(input_fp, 'r') as file, open(output_fp, 'w') as ofp:
    text = file.read()
    result = re.search(r'(?<=%s)[\S\s]*(?=%s)' % (start_key, end_key), text)
    if result:
        print(result.group(0))
```

Output:

```
[more text here]
```

The `(?<=12345-67897\n)[\S\s]*(?=AMOUNT POSTED: \$43,000\.00)` will find any text between those 2 strings for you, the full explanation for this regex can be found [here on regexr](http://regexr.com/6bu9b). Attention to the backward slashes to supress the special meaning of those characters